# Pokemon GBA->DS Transfer/Can you get Charmander in Pokemon Black II

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-black-2-white-2

I'm wanting to get a Charmander into Pokemon Black II and I remembered that there was a Pokemon DS game that granted the possibility of transferring Pokemon from GBA to DS, could anybody tell me which one it was? Or was there even ever a game that did that?

Also if the above is impossible is there a way of catching a Charmander in Pokemon Black II in the wild or through some event or story event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get Charmander without trading from another BW/BW2 game or transferring from DPPt.

The transferring of Pokemon from DPPt is done via the Pokemon Transfer Lab, found on route 15.

[Quote from IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-black-white-version-2/Poke_Transfer_Lab):

> In order to transfer Pokemon, you need two Nintendo DS Systems. The
>   Nintendo 3DS also work for this process. Start wireless communications
>   on the system that is running Pokemon Black or White. The other system
>   with the Gen four Pokemon game will bring up a DS Download Play button
>   at the main menu. Click the button and select six Pokemon from your PC
>   to transfer over to Pokemon Black and White. Remember, once the
>   Pokemon are transferred over, you cannot transfer them back! Not all
>   Pokemon can be transferred:
>
> - Pokemon cannot hold items
> - Select event Pokemon
> - Pokemon Eggs
> - Pokemon with Hidden Machines
>
> After sending Pokemon to the Poke Transfer Lab, you will play a short
>   mini-game. Launch Poke Balls at the Pokemon as they dodge from bush to
>   bush. After all Pokemon are caught, the game will end, and the Pokemon
>   will be transferred to your PC.

Comment: Emm, what does DPPt stand for? Also is this route 15 in Pokemon Black II?

Comment: @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec I'm presuming it's Diamond/Pearl/Platinum (aka fourth generation games)

Comment: @Wojtek'Charkz'Hordyniec Oops, yes, I meant Diamond/Pearl/Platinum :) and yes, the Transfer Lab would be in Route 15 of Pokemon Black 2.

Answer (score 5):

Getting a Pokémon from a GBA (Gen III) game to a Gen V (Black / White / Black 2 / White 2) game is a two-step process.

First, you need a DS 'Phat' (the original model) or a DS Lite and a copy of Pokémon Diamond, Pearl or Platinum. Insert the GBA game into the console's GBA port, start the DS game and import the Pokémon via the Pal Park. As I recall, you may only transfer 6 Pokémon every 24 hours.

For the next step, you need a second DS (or 3DS) console. Go to the Pokémon Transfer Lab in the GenV game, and follow the instructions on how to transfer from Gen IV to Gen V.

There is otherwise no way to obtain a Charmander through the story or an event in Gen V.